# Unable to print glossary in latex

Tags: glossaries, appendix

I have a question regarding the appendix and printing glossary in latex.

I have multiple .tex files, where the main .tex looked like:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{mnthesis}
\usepackage{epsfig,epic,eepic,units}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
%\bibliographystyle{hunsrt}
%\input{my_definitions}

\linespread{2}
\begin{document}
\include{title}
\include{intro}
\include{background}
\include{hypothesis}
\include{experiment}
\include{results}
\include{conclusion}
\appendix
\include{app_glossary}
\end{document}
```

and my `app_glossary` looked like:

```
    \newglossaryentry{something}
{
    name=something,
    description={something}
}
```

However, the page that should be appendix returned an empty page even if I have multiple `\gls{something}` referred in the other `.tex` file. I tried `\glsaddall` and `\printglossary`, none of them worked. Also tried to add appendix as a chapter with `app_glossary`, somehow it showed as appendix in the table of content, but still, no glossary at all.

Do you have any suggestions or advice? Many thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Did you recieve error messages? Which one? Add them to your question please.

Comment: @Mensch Surprisingly I didn't received any error message. It complied successfully, and left the appendix and glossary completely empty

Answer (score 1):

Glossaries don't work like you posted. Instead of `\include{app_glossary}` after `\appendix` you should `\input{app_glossary}` in the preamble of your document. Then use the glossary entry with `\gls{something}` or similar commands in the body of your document. Finally, after `\appendix` you can write `\printglossary` (or `\printglossaries` if you have more than one). So your document should look like this:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside]{mnthesis}
\usepackage{epsfig,epic,eepic,units}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bbm}
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
%\bibliographystyle{hunsrt}
%\input{my_definitions}
\input{app_glossary}% <- glossaries definitions in preamble

\linespread{2}
\begin{document}
\include{title}
\include{intro}
\include{background}
\include{hypothesis}
\include{experiment}
\include{results}
\include{conclusion}
\appendix
\printglossary% <- print the glossary
\end{document}
```

I tested the proposed code changing document class from `mnthesis` to `book`, deleting all the chapters and including a `\gls{something}` (I don't have this class and extra documents)

Comment: Thanks for your post. But it did not work on my end. I tried your approach, the glossaries did not appear, but the empty page run to the very first page. Also I'm afraid I have to use this `mnthesis` document class

Comment: There is a web site in which we can find the `mnthesis` class?

Comment: do you have tried with `glossaries-extra` instead of `glossaries`?

Comment: Here is the link for `mnthesis`:https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/university-of-minnesota-thesis-template/tkngcptkrmgy . It somehow worked on Overleaf, but not work on my local.

Comment: You mean `\usepackage{glossaries-extra}`?